# How do I pass a variable from my local server to a remote server?

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables, quoting

I am trying to pass a variable from my local server (location1) to a remote server (location2). The purpose of the code is to copy a file from the remote server from a predefined location. In simpler terms, I want to copy files from location2 to location1 using a predefined path where location1 is on the local server and location2 is a remote server. See the code segment:

```
$location1=somewhere/on/local_server
$location2=somewhere/on/remote_server

sshpass -p "password" \
  ssh username@74.11.11.11 'su -lc "cp -r $location2 $location1";'
```

The error I get is that both $location1 and $location2 are undefined. Also, I DON'T want to manually type the location paths because they could change at any time and it would be a pain to change them in the code if done manually.

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding what it is you are trying to do. Are you looking for a way to transfer files between two machines? For that you can use `scp`. Example: `scp remote-server:/home/Me/myfile.txt ~/Documents/`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

variables are not expanded between single quotes.

use double quotes and escape the inner double quotes:

```
sshpass -p "password" \
  ssh username@74.11.11.11 "su -lc \"cp -r $location2 $location1\";"
```

or close the single quotes and open them again:

```
sshpass -p "password" \
  ssh username@74.11.11.11 'su -lc "cp -r '$location2' '$location1'";'
```

bash does string concatenation automatically.

note: not tested. might screw up misserably if `$locationX` contains spaces or other weird characters.

Answer (score 6):

A shell variable, is just that: a variable of the shell. The `ssh` command, or the shell started by `sshd` on the remote host have no way to get access to that variable of the client's shell.

*Exported* shell variables are passed as environment variables to executed commands. So if you exported `location1` it would be passed as an environment variable to `ssh`. If you used the `SendEnv` `ssh` configuration directive (via `-o` or `~/.ssh/config` or `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`...), `ssh` would try and send it to `sshd` on the remote host.

However, for that to work, `sshd` would need to have an `AcceptEnv` configuration directive that allows receiving that variable. However, it's generally not the case for security reason.

Many default ssh/sshd deployment however allow passing variables whose name starts with `LC_` (for localisation). So you could leverage that with:

```
LC_location1=$location1 LC_location2=$location2 ssh host 
    'su -lc '\''cp -r -- "$LC_location2" "$LC_location1"'\''
```

Alternatively, you could have the local shell expand the variables in the command line that is passed to the remote shell:

```
ssh host "su -lc 'cp -r -- $location2 $location1'"
```

But that's the equivalent as running:

```
eval eval "cp -r -- $location2 $location1"
```

That is those variables are not passed as arguments to `cp`, they are interpreted (twice) as shell (the login shell of the remote user, and the `sh` started by `su`) code, so if `$location1` is for instance `/somewhere;rm -rf /`, that will have dramatic consequences.

The proper way would be to properly escape those for the remote shell. Because of the two levels of shells, you need to escape the single quotes twice (here using `ksh93`/`bash`/`zsh` syntax):

```
escaped_location1=\'${location1//\'/\'\\\'\'}\'
escaped_location1=${escaped_location1//\'/\'\\\'\'}
escaped_location2=\'${location2//\'/\'\\\'\'}\'
escaped_location2=${escaped_location2//\'/\'\\\'\'}
ssh host "su -lc 'cp -r -- $escaped_location2 $escaped_location1'"
```

That assumes the login shell of the remote user is Bourne-like.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to lesmana's answer: you should quote the variables in his second example.

```
sshpass -p "password" \
  ssh username@74.11.11.11 'su -lc "cp -r '\\\"$location2\\\"' '\\\"$location1\\\"'";'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also be in the following situation: You want to run a program on the remote machine which you cannot change and which reads the variable $FOO. So you need $FOO to be set on the remote machine.

If $FOO does not contain any special shell characters you can do:

```
ssh server FOO=$FOO the_program
```

If $FOO contains special shell characters, then you need to quote those, and that is where it can get quite tricky, and if $FOO contains \n doubly so. That is still doable if you set $FOO yourself. But if $FOO is set by a user you need a program to quote it for you. One solution is (ab)using GNU Parallel:

```
export FOO
parallel -N0 -S server --env FOO the_program ::: ""
```

GNU Parallel knows how to transfer variables with all sorts of special characters. E.g.:

```
FOO='* < " > $ ! # @ ) ( ] [ } { | & % \ ''here is a quoted newline
more of FOO'"'"'s content'
export FOO
parallel -N0 -S localhost --env FOO echo '"$FOO"' ::: ""
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this script I wrote for updating our service.

`PROJ=$2` will be passed to remote running env.

```
function update-env () {
    env=$1
    proj=$2

    # script for update test env
    ssh -A root@$2.$1.test.com PROJ=$2 'bash -s' <<'ENDSSH'
        # commands to run on remote host
        su gmuser
        cd /srv/apps/$PROJ
        /usr/bin/git pull
        exit
        supervisorctl restart $PROJ
    ENDSSH
}
```

Answer (score -1):

just write the variable or data needed to a local file and then in the script run an scp command to send the file to the remote server. on the remote server, have a script that will check periodically (via cron) for the file and read it's contents and do whatever you want it to do.